# Python - Sum each column into a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, if-statement

I need help with looping/if statements in Python. I have a df called "main" and another df that I created called "estimates". I would like to sum the columns based on certain conditions in main and populate it in "estimates" df.

(main)

| ID | Score | W | B | H | A | PE | F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RDL | 2 | 9 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| RDL | 4 | 8 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| BAP | 6 | 7 | 5 | 8 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| BAP | 8 | 10 | 9 | 2 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| RDL | 10 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Then I have another df (estimates) that is empty but would like to fill based on some conditions from the above:

| ID | Type | W | B | H | A | Yes/No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

*if ID=RDL and PE=0, **sum** all and put "RON" in Type and "Yes" in Yes/No* so the results in "estimates" should be:

| ID | Type | W | B | H | A | Yes/No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RDL | RON | 19 | 6 | 10 | 7 | Yes |

I hope I explained this right but if not, please let me know so I can clarify!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you want to avoid looping over rows in `pandas` because it is less efficient. You can do this instead:

```py
summary = df[(df['ID']=='RDL') & (df['PE']==0)].sum()
df_estimates.loc[df['ID']=='RDL', 'Type'] = 'RON'
df_estimates.loc[df['ID']=='RDL', 'W'] = summary['W']
df_estimates.loc[df['ID']=='RDL', 'B'] = summary['B']
df_estimates.loc[df['ID']=='RDL', 'H'] = summary['H']
df_estimates.loc[df['ID']=='RDL', 'A'] = summary['A']
df_estimates.loc[df['ID']=='RDL', 'Yes/No'] = 'Yes'

print(df_estimates)
ID  Type    W   B   H   A   Yes/No
0   RDL RON 17  6   10  7   Yes
```

**EDIT FOLLOWING COMMENT:**

Sorry, I didn't realize that you wanted to populate an empty dataframe.

Instead of creating and empty dataframe defining the column names, you can create the empty dataframe *without* column names and then create the columns on the fly when assinging them a value:

```py
# df is your main dataframe

# select rows based on your condition and sum all
summary = df[(df['ID']=='RDL') & (df['PE']==0)].sum()

# create empty dataframe
emptytable = pd.DataFrame()

# create columns and assign their values
emptytable['ID'] = ['RON']
emptytable['Yes/No'] = ['Yes']
emptytable['ID'] = ['RDL']

emptytable['W'] = summary['W']
emptytable['B'] = summary['B']
emptytable['H'] = summary['H']
emptytable['A'] = summary['A']

emptytable

     ID     Yes/No  W   B   H   A
0   RDL     Yes     17  6   10  7
```

Another possibility is to create the estimates dataframe with the values you want (`RDL` and `Yes` on your example), and then use merge:

```py
df_estimates = pd.DataFrame([['RDL', 'Yes']], columns=['ID', 'Yes/No'])

df_estimates

    ID  Yes/No
0   RDL     Yes

summary = df[(df['ID']=='RDL') & (df['PE']==0)]
summary = summary.groupby(['ID'])['W', 'B', 'H', 'A'].sum()

summary

         W  B   H   A
ID              
RDL     17  6   10  7


df_estimates.merge(summary, on='ID')

     ID     Yes/No  W   B   H   A
0   RDL     Yes     17  6   10  7
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it but I think there may be something wrong with my empty columns? I get an error that says "cannot set a frame with no defined index and a scalar" :(. I'll look into this more.

Comment: Hi again! I keep receiving an error that says "cannot set a frame with no defined index and a scalar" every time I try to run this in the empty data frame. Here is the empty table code:


emptytable = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ID', Yes/No', 
                                     'Type', 'B' 'H', 'A', 'AN', 'MO', 'W']) 
print(emptytable)


@ibmx